# ¿Como declarar un constructor sin argumentos?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, constructor

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los documentos desde firebase y convertirlos directamente en un objeto pero me salta con el siguiente error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.chdzma.changeproject.objects.Food does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped

Y esta es la clase:

```
class Food(name:String, description: String, calories: Int, carbo: Int, fats: Int, proteins: Int, sodium: Int, sugar: Int) : Item{

    val name = name
    val description = description
    val calories = calories
    val carbo = carbo
    val fats = fats
    val proteins = proteins
    val sodium = sodium
    val sugar = sugar

    override fun getViewType(): Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo define un constructor vacio, esto es necesario para capturar datos desde firebase

```
class Food(){

 }

class Food(name:String, description: String, calories: Int, carbo: Int, fats: Int, proteins: Int, sodium: Int, sugar: Int) : Item{

    val name = name
    val description = description
    val calories = calories
    val carbo = carbo
    val fats = fats
    val proteins = proteins
    val sodium = sodium
    val sugar = sugar

    override fun getViewType(): Int {
        return 1
    }
```